# Error al Instalar supervisor en Raspbian

Tags: python, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

tengo una *Raspberry Pi 3 Model B*

En la cual tengo instalado **Raspbian** via [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) en su versión actual que a la fecha es **2.4.4**

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de como configurar **Django + Ngnix + Gunicorn** en el siguiente [Enlace](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/), el inconveniente es que en uno de los pasos me pide instalar `supervisor` pero al correr en consola el comando para instalar:

```
$ sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

Me esta devolviendo el siguiente error la terminal:

```
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes adicionales:
  python-meld3
Paquetes sugeridos:
  supervisor-doc
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  python-meld3 supervisor
0 actualizados, 2 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 70 no actualizados.
Se necesita descargar 317 kB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 1.604 kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
Des:1 http://raspbian.c3sl.ufpr.br/raspbian stretch/main armhf python-meld3 all 1.0.2-2 [37,3 kB]
Des:2 http://raspbian.c3sl.ufpr.br/raspbian stretch/main armhf supervisor all 3.3.1-1+deb9u1 [280 kB]
Descargados 317 kB en 4s (66,9 kB/s)
Seleccionando el paquete python-meld3 previamente no seleccionado.
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 126839 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparando para desempaquetar .../python-meld3_1.0.2-2_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando python-meld3 (1.0.2-2) ...
Seleccionando el paquete supervisor previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../supervisor_3.3.1-1+deb9u1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando supervisor (3.3.1-1+deb9u1) ...
Configurando python-meld3 (1.0.2-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete python-meld3 (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de supervisor:
 supervisor depende de python-meld3; sin embargo:
 El paquete `python-meld3' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete supervisor (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
Procesando disparadores para systemd (232-25+deb9u1) ...
Procesando disparadores para man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 python-meld3
 supervisor
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Alguien tuvo el mismo problema, como lo soluciono, desde ya muchas gracias.

**Actualizacíon**

Me olvide de aclarar, configure **Python3.5** como versión por defecto, y al parecer el modulo `ConfigParse` en Python3 fue renombrado a `configparse` por lo que parece que esa es la razon del problema, tratare de poner por defecto de nuevo Python2.7 y les cuento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente el problema radicaba que `supervisor` no esta compilado para **python3** sino para **python2**

Comprobamos la versión de python por defecto

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.10
```

por lo que para volver a python2 tuve que hacer

```
$ update-alternatives --config python

Existen 2 opciones para la alternativa python (que provee /usr/bin/python).

Selección   Ruta                Prioridad  Estado
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.5   1         modo automático
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   0         modo manual
  2            /usr/bin/python3.5   1         modo manual
Pulse <Intro> para mantener el valor por omisión [*] o pulse un número de selección: 1
```

luego comprobar la versión y efectivamente se cambio a Python2

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

Ahora correr el comando para instalar `supervisor` y ya no generara problema

```
$ sudo apt-get install supervisor
```